# Rspec error: unknown format for create action using json format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, rspec

Create method

```
def create
  @user = User.new(user_params) 
  if @user.save
    respond_with("User #{@user.id}.", code: 200)
  else
    respond_with("User creation failed #{@user.errors}", code: 500)
  end
end
```

My specs:

```
describe "POST 'create'" do
  context "with valid parameters" do
    let(:credentials) { { :email => "new_user@example.net", :company_id => 1 } }
  it "creates a new user" do
    expect { post :create, :user => credentials }.to change(User, :count).by(1)
  end
```

Gives error: `Unknown format`

When code changed to `expect { post :create, :user => credentials, :format => json }.to change(User, :count).by(1)` error is:

```
undefined local variable or method `json'
```

What is the right way to spec for json response?

Comment: format should be a string or symbol. it should be `:format => 'json'` or `:format => :json`

Comment: after I did your changes, I get this error:  undefined method `User 4._url' ?? no clue what this error is.

Comment: @Oatmeal, have a look at this article: http://archives.ryandaigle.com/articles/2009/8/6/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-cleaner-restful-controllers-w-respond_with to understand how `respond_with` works